# How to write import statement instead of require statement in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I was importing one of the polyfill, "es6-promise" in my jsx file of react application but was not able to import it in a correct way.

I googled N number of solution finally one worked for IE.
 `require('es6-promise').polyfill()`

its working fine but, why it was not working for  `import es6-promise from "es6-promise";` 
Is there any way to import it first in a variable and then calling the .polyfill() method to that variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There a multiple ways of how you can import other modules in your code: [import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import)

For example:

```
import * as ES6Promise from 'es6-promise';

ES6Promise.polyfill();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a couple more ways you can do it.

```
import { polyfill } from 'es6-promise';
polyfill();
```

or

```
import ES6Promise from 'es6-promise';
ES6Promise.polyfill();
```